# Variables not saving

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm trying to write web server code. However, I am having trouble with part of it.

Currently, to get it to save a bool variable I have it use a pin, as when I ran the code without it, after the page refreshes it resets the variable to its original value.

How do I get it to save the variable in this code without it using the pin?

```
digitalWrite (equalPin, server.arg("equal").toInt());
char equalText[80];
if(equalState) {
  strcpy(equalText, "priority is equal. <a href=\"/?equal=0\">Deactivate</a>");
  equalState = false;
} else {
  strcpy(equalText, "priority is not equal. <a href=\"/?equal=1\">Activate</a>");
  equalState = true;
}
equalState = digitalRead(equalPin);
```

I also have several over copies of this for different pages but if I change 1 of them they all change and reset after 10 seconds.

The code follows the example on [this site](https://42bots.com/tutorials/esp8266-example-wi-fi-access-point-web-server-static-ip-remote-control/).

Comment: so you want to set it or leave it as is? in `if` and `else` you change it and then you revert to the value before `if` and `else`. perhaps learn coding first.

Comment: I want it to set it then potentially change again in the future. I remeber doing it in the past but ive completely forgotten how. How do I stop it from reverting?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Perhaps someone else can, but perhaps writing the question more clearly would help you get more responses. Consider a minimal, complete, verifiable example (Google to find what that is).

Comment: What are your trying to achieve? The code you linked to presumably works fine. Please, state clearly the purpose of your modifications.

Answer (score 1):

same code snippet without using pin

```
char equalText[80];

if (equalState){
  strcpy(equalText, "priority is equal. <a href=\"/?equal=0\">Deactivate</a>");
  equalState = false;
}
else {
  strcpy(equalText, "priority is not equal. <a href=\"/?equal=1\">Activate</a>");
  equalState = true;
}
equalState = server.arg("equal").toInt();
```

but it does not make much sense to set the value if you already switched the state based on it's previous value

Comment: That seems to have worked it just doesnt auto refresh the page anymore but thats fine.